# getting error in cron : require: command not found

Tags: php, cron

I have set the cron with this command : `/mnt/md4/test/public_html/wp-content/plugins/website-custom-plugin/WCP/FrontEnd/cron.php`, it runs every 2 mins, i got it's email output and getting this error in that cron, can anyone please help me to resolve this issue ?

```
/mnt/md4/test/public_html/wp-content/plugins/website-custom-plugin/WCP/FrontEnd/cron.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
/mnt/md4/test/public_html/wp-content/plugins/website-custom-plugin/WCP/FrontEnd/cron.php: line 3: require: command not found
/mnt/md4/test/public_html/wp-content/plugins/website-custom-plugin/WCP/FrontEnd/cron.php: line 4: include: command not found
/mnt/md4/test/public_html/wp-content/plugins/website-custom-plugin/WCP/FrontEnd/cron.php: line 5: global: command not found
/mnt/md4/test/public_html/wp-content/plugins/website-custom-plugin/WCP/FrontEnd/cron.php: line 6: =: command not found
/mnt/md4/test/public_html/wp-content/plugins/website-custom-plugin/WCP/FrontEnd/cron.php: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/mnt/md4/test/public_html/wp-content/plugins/website-custom-plugin/WCP/FrontEnd/cron.php: line 7: `$inventory_data = $wpdb->get_results($inventory_query);'
```

Here is my full code of my cron script

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php';
include 'iCal.php';
global $wpdb;
$inventory_query = "SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."inventory_ical";
$inventory_data = $wpdb->get_results($inventory_query);

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//dfsfsf

foreach($inventory_data as $key => $value) {
    $ical_airbnb = $value->ical_airbnb;
    $inventory_id = $value->inventory_id;

    $file = $ical_airbnb;
    $iCal = new iCal($file);
    $events = $iCal->eventsByDate();
    foreach ($events as $date => $event) { 

        $title = $event[0]->uid;
        $summary = '';
        if(isset($event[0]->summary)) {
            $summary = $event[0]->summary;
        }
        $description = '';
        if(isset($event[0]->description)) {
            $description = $event[0]->description;
        }
        $dateStart = $event[0]->dateStart;
        $dateEnd = $event[0]->dateEnd;
        $location = '';
        if(isset($event[0]->location)) {
            $location = $event[0]->location;
        }

        $airbnb_query = "SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."rnb_availability WHERE block_by = 'AIRBNB' 
                        AND  pickup_datetime =  '".$dateStart."' AND  return_datetime =  '".$dateEnd."' AND inventory_id = '".$inventory_id."' ORDER BY created_at DESC ";
        $airbnb_data = $wpdb->get_results($airbnb_query);

        if(empty($airbnb_data)) {
            $data = array('post_type'=>'shop_order');
            $order_id = $wpdb->insert_id;
            $data = array('pickup_datetime'=>$dateStart,'return_datetime'=>$dateEnd,'inventory_id'=>$inventory_id,'order_id'=>$order_id,'block_by'=>'AIRBNB','created_at'=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),'description'=>$description);
            $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix."rnb_availability",$data);
        }
    }  
    $data = get_order_data($inventory_id,"1");
    //echo '<pre>';
    //print_r($data);
    create_ical($data,'ical_complete_'.$inventory_id.'.ical');  

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the complete line in your cron-file?

Comment: /mnt/md4/test/public_html/wp-content/plugins/website-custom-plugin/WCP/FrontEnd/cron.php

Comment: You need to tell cron to execute the file as PHP: `/path/to/php /mnt/.../cron.php`.

Comment: There probably is no `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` when you run that script from CLI

Answer (score 0):

you can use absolute url to call cron file like 
'lynx source "http://test.com/cron.php" '